# FTP Behind Firewall and Dynamic IP Address

Tags: ftp, firewall, dynamic-ip

I'm currently working on a client project and I get access to files via FTP. Their server is behind a firewall and they're asking me for my IP address, I'm guessing for whitelisting.

Problem is, my IP address is dynamic and it changes quite a lot throughout the day. Is there anyway around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid paying for a static IP is to carry on using a dynamic IP address, but use a dynamic DNS provider such as No-IP which you can cause to update every time your IP address changes (routers will often do this for you automatically, or there are Windows / OSX / Linux (such as ddclient) clients). That way, you can just use something like magpie.no-ip.com instead of an IP address and it will always resolve to your public address.

You can find the whole answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/455226/can-you-configure-dynamic-to-be-static-yourself-without-changing-your-isp

Comment: So they can whitelist magpie.no-ip.com instead of my IP address?